# Direct read data from a file png

Tags: png

is required to read data from a binary file without loading them in Bitmap because it is too much, more than 20000x20000 pixels, I need to open a file, one line at a time to read a file for processing. found an example for reading BMP, can not understand how in the same way to get data from PNG.

```
        byte[] B = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        GCHandle GCH = GCHandle.Alloc(B, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr Scan0 = (IntPtr)((int)(GCH.AddrOfPinnedObject()) + 54);
        int W = Marshal.ReadInt32(Scan0, -36);
        int H = Marshal.ReadInt32(Scan0, -32);
        Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(W, H, 4 * W, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, Scan0);
        GCH.Free();
        return Bmp;
```

Language C#

Comment: i suggest you review this :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Comment: 0

down vote

accept
 

I read this description, but to be honest I have beyond the understanding of the format of the file is too much further calculations, and no (((I need other on one line of pixels and handle it, all the work is already fully described, rested only in the size of the file that he just does not open due to a memory overflow error when using the Bitmap. If you can bring code reading 1st line with pixels ... I'll just be very grateful

Comment: how about telling us (tag!) the programming language?

Comment: I did not quite understand what you said

Comment: You force us to guess the programming language (C? C# Java ?) There are more than one, you know.

Comment: sorry for my english, ( lang c#

Comment: programming language  c#

Comment: This question will probably be closed due to low quality -anayway: you can also try PngCs library (google)

Answer (score 0):

I found a library (PNGChunkParser) with parsing blocks APG has received all the blocks that are in the file, I found a 21 unit Idate, but trying to paint them 50 lines, to be not the right picture:

```
byte[] B = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        List<byte> tmpb = new List<byte>();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(B))
        {
            PNGChunk[] chunks = PNGChunkParser.ChunksFromStream(stream).ToArray();
            foreach (PNGChunk item in chunks)
            {
                if (item.TypeString == "IDAT")
                {
                    PNGChunk idatChunk = item;
                    foreach (byte s in idatChunk.Data)
                    {
                        tmpb.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var size_png = ImageHelper.GetDimensions(filename);
        GetConturPic(tmpb.ToArray(), size_png.Width, 50,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);          
         private void GetConturPic(byte[] data, int w, int h, PixelFormat pixel_format)
    {
        int index;
        int stride = GetStride(w, pixel_format);
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(w, h);
        Color fm = new Color();
        try
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
                {
                    index = y * stride + 4 * x;
                    fm = GetPixelColor(data, w, h, x, y,

             System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(pixel_format));
                    bm.SetPixel(x, y, fm);
                }
                pictureBox1.Image = bm;
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public Color GetPixelColor(byte[] Pixels, int w, int h, int x, int y, int depth)
    {
        Color clr = Color.Empty;
        // Get color components count
        int cCount = depth / 8;
        // Get start index of the specified pixel
        int i = ((y * w) + x) * cCount;
        if (i > Pixels.Length - cCount)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        byte b, g, a, r, c;
        switch (depth)
        {
            case 32:
                b = Pixels[i];
                g = Pixels[i + 1];
                r = Pixels[i + 2];
                a = Pixels[i + 3]; // a
                clr = Color.FromArgb(a, b, g, r);
                break;
            case 24:
                b = Pixels[i];
                g = Pixels[i + 1];
                r = Pixels[i + 2];
                clr = Color.FromArgb(b, g, r);
                break;
            case 8:
                c = Pixels[i];
                clr = Color.FromArgb(c, c, c);
                break;
        }
        return clr;
    }
```

help what need to do to get 50 lines of image ?